# Bootstrap center text over input box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap issue where I'm having trouble centering text over the middle input box with "text-center". I'm guessing this has to do something with padding, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue. The "Apply Now" H2 tag is not aligned in the middle of the input box underneath.

```
<div class="text-center"><h2>Apply Now</h2></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray text-center ", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray text-center ", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray placeholder-left ", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the code that should fix your problem. Treat each column seperately. Add two full with col-md-12 entries which will wrap and become two lines tall. You can then center the text in the first entry.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2>Apply Now</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray placeholder-left ", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still having the same issue.  The "Apply Now" isn't centered over the middle text box.  It's over to the right for some reason :(

Comment: I screwed that one up. I'm forced to work with a restricted browser and it doesn't play nicely with stack overflow. It looks like I over wrote the original question.

Comment: The <h2>Apply Now</h2> is still not centered over the middle text box.  This one is baffling to me...

Comment: I'm thinking you have something else affecting the layout. I place the code sample I posted into an mostly empty .cshtml file and it looked great. The Apply Now was directly centered over the middle column.

Comment: Hmm, yes I believe I have something overriding the default layout.  I did as you said and tried it in an empty cshtml file and it worked.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your browsing history? External css saves in the cache so you won't see you changes to the css if you won't clear the history because the browser tends to use the css prior to the change.

If this doesn't work, how about putting the css/class in the heading itself?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Apply Now</h2>
    <!--<h2 class="text-center">Apply Now</h2>-->
</div>
```